# How do I override the onClick for TextView links? - Android

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView inside a ListView.

The textview has links in it, and I have this property set:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

I have reference to the TextView inside the **ArrayAdapter**.  When I click the link, it throws this error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: Please post your adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

I was initializing the ArrayAdapter w/ the applicationcontext